# selenium testing gwt wizard

Tags: selenium-rc

i m doing selenium testing against an gwt wizard application, as a wizard, there are multiple steps, once user finish one step and click next, it transfer to next step, as gwt application, all steps are refreshed in the same page.

now i need to use selenium RC (java client) to write test against that gwt wizard and have 2 questions:
1. each time i start the wizard it require user login first, how can i avoid that login step to test the wizard directly?
2. since all steps are hold on the same page, how can i separate the test, say one test method for each step, without put the test in one big method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Selenium2/Webdriver.  Selenium 2 has the concept of page objects which allow you to create test objects which map to different pages within your app.  I assume that you are enabling ensureDebugId in your gwt app (which allows you to access elements based on a predictable dom id).  The combination of debugIds and selenium2 will allow you to quickly create a clean test representation of your pages and then allow your unit tests to simply drive the pages to where you need.  The last bit of advice I would give for selenium2 and gwt is make sure that your page objects are created via AjaxElementLocatorFactory.